# How to solve this type of problems?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm struggling in solving this equation and tried to use the elimination method but did not work with me. Can anyone please show me how it can be solved?

$$
-555=0.862X+0.138Y-0.345Z, \\
-911=0.413X+0.587Y-0.492Z,\\
674=0.849X+0.142Y+0.358Z,\\
$$

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this algebra precalc, or is it linear algebra?

Comment: Gaussian elimination should work, you're probably making a mistake somewhere (or the system is insolvable, but it doesn't look like it). Please post what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: "did not work with me": what went wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Solve the first equation for $X$.
- Substitute $X$ into the second equation and solve for $Y$.
- Substitute $Y$ into the third equation and find $Z$.
- Use this to find $Y$ and $X$ from the first two equations.

You should end up with:

$$X=79.2468, Y=-140.527, Z=1750.49$$

Note that there are **many** other ways to solve this, for example Gaussian Elimination or Cramer's Rule, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think you're studying computational mathematics. The alternative to usual precise methods ([Gauss–Jordan elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) used in most online calculators) is iterative methods. It may be [Jacobi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method), or [Gauss-Seidel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) (classical).